# Mongoose - why cast date is failed?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to filter values from the collections with range of 2 dates:

```
const filterPattern = {
  createdAt: {
    '&gte': 2020-10-09T14:18:07.240Z,
    '&lte': 2020-12-09T14:26:49.544Z
  }
};

CollectionName.find(filterPattern);
```

But get an error:

```
CastError: Cast to date failed for value "{ '&gte': 2020-10-09T, '&lte': 2020-12-09T14:26:49.544Z }" at path "createdAt" for...
```

Both of the values *'&gte'* and *'&lte'* I've created by *new Date()* and they return *true* after *instanceof Date*.

What wrong there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `$` instead of `&` and set the values accordingly:

```
const filterPattern = {
  createdAt: {
     $gte: "2020-10-09T14:18:07.240Z",
     $lte: "2020-12-09T14:26:49.544Z"
  }
};
```